# Get the callers phone number from an incoming call on iPhone

Tags: ios, core-telephony

I'm trying to get caller ID (phone number) at the time of incoming call.
TrueCaller has implemented this and they get the phone number of incoming caller.

I've found this information:
1. CoreTelephony Framework(It gives only calling states)
2. Apple's 9.0 update : "Maybe" contacts sync. with mail app and detects the incoming phone number.

Comment: Caller ID only works on jailbroken devices...

Comment: True caller doesn't get the caller id. Rather they add known spam numbers to a contact in the phone book and this contact has the "spam" image

Comment: Yes, but check their latest update. They implemented that thing also published intro message on their web site to.https://www.truecaller.com/articles/iphone

Comment: Truecaller Brings A New Way to Search from Call History on iOS 9
The recent release of iOS 9 has the Apple community over the moon with new and improved features, and here at Truecaller we are loving all the possibilities of this update too!

Comment: It has always been in our DNA to bring the best possible version of our app to all platforms, and today, that’s exactly what we’re doing with iOS 9! We know our loyal Apple fanatics of Truecaller have been looking for an easier, faster way to find out who has called them.

Truecaller brings a new action extension for our users, including an exciting search function for unknown numbers that is built directly into your call history and messages. This will definitely enhance your ability to search faster than ever using Truecaller. Interested? We thought so!

Comment: So, how does it work?
Phone App: Truecaller is introducing a shortcut to find out who called from an unknown number - directly from your call history!
Step 1) Open your phone app and go to ‘Recents’.
Step 2) Tap the ‘i’ icon on an unknown number.
Step 3) Tap ‘Share Contact’.
Step 4) Tap ‘More’ to enable the Truecaller search plugin.

Comment: Messaging App: Searching for an unknown number from your message app? No problem!

Step 1) Open the message app and click on the unknown message.
Step 2) Tap the ‘i’ icon in the top right corner.
Step 3) Tap ‘Share Contact’.
Step 4) Tap ‘More’ to enable the ‘Search in Truecaller’ plugin.

Now you can search Truecaller instantly from your phone and messaging apps! The new update can be found on the App Store, or by downloading the app from our website *Only for iOS 9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**###EDIT###**

**iOS 10 and above:**

Use [Callkit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit), take a look at call directory extension

*According to documentation,*

***Identifying Incoming Callers***

When a phone receives an incoming call, the system first consults the user’s contacts to find a matching phone number. If no match is found, the system then consults your app’s Call Directory extension to find a matching entry to identify the phone number. This is useful for applications that maintain a contact list for a user that’s separate from the system contacts, such as a social network, or for identifying incoming calls that may be initiated from within the app, such as for customer service support or a delivery notification.

For example, consider a user who is friends with Jane in a social networking app, but doesn’t have her phone number in her contacts. The social networking app has a Call Directory Extension, which downloads and add the phone numbers of all of the user’s friends. Because of this, when the user gets an incoming call from Jane, the system displays something like “(App Name) Caller ID: Jane Appleseed” rather than “Unknown Caller”.

To provide identifying information about incoming callers, you use the addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:label:) method in the implementation of beginRequest(with:).

```
class CustomCallDirectoryProvider: CXCallDirectoryProvider {
    override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        let labelsKeyedByPhoneNumber: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber: String] = [ … ]
        for (phoneNumber, label) in labelsKeyedByPhoneNumber.sorted(by: <) {
            context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: label)        
        }

        context.completeRequest()
    }
}
```

Because this method is called only when the system launches the app extension and not for each individual call, you must specify call identification information all at once; you cannot, for example, make a request to a web service to find information about an incoming call.

**iOS 9 and earlier:**

As Kakshil mentioned, **Caller ID is not possible on non jailbroken devices.**

And I will give you some findings on how true caller works,

1. Its not reading the call history, they actually created [Action
   extension](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794), wherever you try to share a contact, it will display
   truecaller app extension, which coded for showing the contact
   details fetched from their server
2. You might also get confused with push notification received for few
   calls, saying
       "Some X calls you". This is where truecaller used a trick. If you
       noticed clearly, that push notification will be received only when
       you get a call from an android user with truecaller installed. Let
       me explain you in details,

X(android user with truecaller installed), calling Y(ios user with truecaller installed), the android version notify the server that X making call to Y. And server will send push notification to Y's iPhone.

Comment: but truecaller give incoming call detail in call tab of truecaller application

Comment: @SaurabhJain Are you getting all the incoming calls inside truecaller application?

Comment: No sir, I Get only some incoming call

Comment: @SaurabhJain Also with iOS 10, apple allow apps to for caller identification using Callkit, but the user should enable under Settings->Phone->Call Blocking & identification

Comment: @SaurabhJain Thats the trick, if a call make from ios truecaller/android mobile to your number, the store the data in therir server, and notify you, showing as in your logs.

Comment: can Call blocking and identification give the incoming call detail in iOS 10?

Comment: @SaurabhJaini have revised my answer, please take  look at the extension, that may help you

Comment: Sir, I work on extension, It identify or block the number which is given in call directory extension, but how can i know the incoming call detail in my application.

Comment: @SaurabhJain You can get the complete incoming calls, thats why even in truecaller you are not getting the complete list. That actually made a workaround.

Comment: Sir, If the phone number save in my contact list, So can i get the phone number in my app?

Comment: Please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837561/how-to-use-call-directory-extension-to-identify-a-incoming-call-in-my-applicatio

Answer (score 1):

Caller ID is not possible on non jailbroken devices.

However there is one way, in which you can know which user is calling, but not sure if it will be useful to you.

If you have a bluetooth device, connected to the iPhone, it will get all notifications, including incoming calls, which you can then get the caller ID for.

Apart from this, there is currently no other way at all to know the called ID.

Comment: Thanks Kakshil, But please check "TrueCaller" app. They access call log & incoming call number(i guess). They released latest build on 9th-May-2016.https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/truecaller-number-search-spam/id448142450?mt=8