# Swift IOS get notified about incoming calls for defined phone numbers

Tags: ios, swift, phone-number, phone-call, callkit

I am developing an App where a special action is executed when the user gets called by one of a few predefined telephone numbers.

I understand, that I cannot receive the numbers of all incoming calls for privacy reasons and this is not what I really need as well.

I simply want to define something like 10 phone numbers and only execute an action when one of this numbers calls me.

The idea behind that is, that when one of this persons call me, I want to send a command to a BLE device to make it blink. So a physical call notifier only for special phonenumbers defined by my App.
On Android this is easily possible by using the PhoneStateListener + onCallStateChanged event.

I am happy about any hint towards the right direction.
Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: This Questions differs from [Get the callers phone number from an incoming call on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161222/get-the-callers-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call-on-iphone) because I do not want to get the callers number but I only want to be informed about an incoming call from any of the defined numbers. Do not even care about which of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the callers phone number from an incoming call on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161222/get-the-callers-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call-on-iphone)

Comment: You would be better off having the BLE device use the ANCS service so that it gets the details of all incoming calls and then the device itself can recognise the special numbers.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you very much about the hint towards that. That has been my backup plan already, but forces me to put more logic into the BLE device which is a bit unfortunate but I will have to do it that way I fear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CallKit only allows your own VoIP app to gain access to the native phone UI. It does not allow you to create an app that is able to interact with calls coming to the native phone app (the device's actual phone number). So if you created your own VoIP app that receives calls then you can use the Call Directory functionality to work with incoming calls, but you are not able to use Call Directory to have your app gain access to the system phone.