# Can you store incoming phone numbers as a variable on iOs?

Tags: ios, swift

Im writing an application for iOs.  However I've run into a problem where some sources seem to say this is impossible while others seemingly hint that it is in fact possible.  Basically what I want my application to do, (and yes i know iOs already has this feature) is to take the number of an incoming call, and send a SMS back with a "busy message".

For instance, 555-555-5555 calls me, my app responds to 555-555-5555 with a text message saying, "Sorry i'm busy!"

Comment: iOS can do this, but your app can't. When your phone is ringing you can select a message to send back to the caller.  For privacy reasons your app can't find out any details of incoming calls.

Answer (score 0):

Caller ID is not possible, but you can use Apple [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit).

Maybe this answer may have any hint that might help you out: [Get the callers phone number from an incoming call on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161222/get-the-callers-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call-on-iphone)